# Text wrapping in Terminology

Tags: terminal, ps, terminology, enlightenment, wrap

I just installed Enlightenment in OpenSuse Tumbleweed via YasT. I'm using E as the WM and entrance as the DM, if it matters.

While checking its terminal emulator Terminology, I noticed that output lines larger than the width of the window get clipped i.e. if my window is 120 chars wide and the command output 150 chars,only the first 120 chars of the output are printed - the rest is neither wrapped nor hidden "beyond the window border". If I resize the window to 150+ chars and rerun the command, I can see the full output.

I looked in Terminology's settings but didn't find a relevant attribute. The choice of names for both the WM and the emulator doesn't help when searching online and I've had no luck.

Thanks.

Comment: Does it work as expected in other terminal emulators? Does the command `echo -ne '\e[?7h'` by any chance fix it for you?

Comment: @egmont Thanks. I get the same behaviour in xterm and yakuake. I ran that command inside the shell but no change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

False alarm! The command in question was `ps aux`. As it [turns out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14057810/5726027), ps truncates its output as per the value of columns when the output is a terminal - seems like a bug. Running `ps auxww` resolves it. This was never an issue with the terminal emulator or the shell.